# C3js timeseries chart generates overlapping bars

Tags: c3.js, timeserieschart

The timeseries chart for my CSV data generates overlapping bars. Is there an issue with the library?  Attaching the image, my code and my CSV data (Which is parsed into a JSON `final_data` before using in code).

[image]

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'date',
        xFormat: '%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p',
        json: final_data,
        keys: {
            x: 'date',
            value: values
        },
        type: 'bar',
        groups: val
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%b %d',
                centered: true,
                fit: true
            }
        }
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true
    },
    color: {
        pattern: colors
    }
});
```

Here's the CSV data I have.

```
Time Series,Category,Duration
6/24/15 12:00 AM,Post Processor,0
6/24/15 12:00 AM,Response Processing,8
6/24/15 12:00 AM,External Calls,168
6/24/15 12:00 AM,Internal Processing,16
6/24/15 12:00 AM,Pre Processor,0
10/1/14 12:00 AM,Post Processor,0
10/1/14 12:00 AM,Response Processing,0
10/1/14 12:00 AM,External Calls,0
10/1/14 12:00 AM,Internal Processing,5
10/1/14 12:00 AM,Pre Processor,0
5/15/15 12:00 AM,Post Processor,0
5/15/15 12:00 AM,Response Processing,0
5/15/15 12:00 AM,External Calls,0
5/15/15 12:00 AM,Internal Processing,5
5/15/15 12:00 AM,Pre Processor,0
```

Answer (score 1):

use bar with, after the data like

```js
bar: {
        //width: {
           // ratio: 0.3 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
      //  }
     
        width: 15 // this makes bar width 100px
    },
```

you can refer this http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you can solve in the next way:

```
var time = ['6/24/15 12:00', '6/24/15 12:00', ...]
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['bar1', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
            ['bar2', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            ['bar3', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        ],
        type: 'bar'
    },
    bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.8
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            tick: {
                count: time.length,
                format: (i) => time[i]
            }
        }
    },
...
});
```

The main point is not to use timeseries at all, and instead of it use tick property and return value for each bar stack by index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a [bug](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/669), timeseries step mus be constant. You can add null values to go around it.